# How to update a variable with a new value through a click event and undo it with the same event

Tags: javascript

While working on a project recently I have got to face this problem

I'm a beginner in JavaScript
And now I can't find the solution for it

There is a thing in JavaScript called toggle

Like,

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function run() {
    btn.classList.toggle('big')
})
```

Here the btn variable is a button in my web.
Following the code, if I click on the btn , a class called big will be added to the element and if I click the btn again , the class will be removed

I want to do something similar
Suppose I have a variable called box and the value is 'empty'

```
const box = 'empty'
```

Now I have a btn and it's clickable.What I want is when the btn is clicked , the value of box will be changed to 'full'
And when I click it again it will be changed to 'empty' again

Help me to find the solution pls

Comment: `let isFull = false;`, `isFull = !isFull;`, or: `box = box == 'empty' ? 'full' : 'empty';`…

Comment: agree to above, but don´t use `const` as u are changing it and its not constant ;)

Comment: Thank you both of you guys
But I couldn't figure out the solution you have provided
But I found my own solution
And it's something like this
`const btn = document.querySelector('.button');
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

let color = 'green'

function varToggle() {
  if (color == 'green') {
    color = 'red';
  }
  else {
    color = 'green';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function bla() {
  varToggle();
  btn.style.background = color;
})`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this and it seamed the easiest way to me

It's something like this

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.button');
const ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

let color = 'green'

function varToggle() {
  if (color == 'green') {
    color = 'red';
  }
  else {
    color = 'green';
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function bla() {
  varToggle();
  btn.style.background = color;
})
```